# How to pass object to directive through attribute in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to pass object (reference - two way binding) through ATTRIBUTE not by isolated scope. How can I do this? Because code bellow passing string instead of object:

HTML

```
<tr ng-form="rowForm" myDirective="{{row.data}}">
```

Directive

```
angular.module("app").directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        require: ["^form"],
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return attrs.myDirective;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            // .....
```

Answer (score 5):

Directives can do two-way data binding without parsing or compile anything manually, sorry for not delivering the plunker but it's rebelius and won't save for me

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myObj = {name: 'Tibro', age: 255}
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      'myAttribute': '='
    },
    template: '{{myAttribute}}',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.myAttribute.age= 31
    }
  }
})
```

#### HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    controller: {{myObj}} <br/>
    directive: <my-directive my-attribute="myObj"></my-directive>
  </body>
```

---

### OUTPUT

```
controller: {"name":"Tibro","age":31} 
directive: {"name":"Tibro","age":31}
```

you can see from the output that passed object has been binded two-way and change made in directive is reflected on controller level

Comment: Let's say I will deal with a isolate scope. In directive in part "link: {...}" I have a function scope.doSomthing. How can I run this function in html (ng-click) if scope is isolated?

Comment: is the `doSomething` in the scope of directive or controller, what's your use case?

Comment: Here: `link: function(scope){
      scope.doSomething = function() {...}
    }` And I want to call it in html by ng-click="doSomething()". Before I added isolated `scope: { }` to directive, everything was working

Comment: You can still do it `template: '<button ng-click="doSomething()">do smth</button>'`

Comment: I have this button in HTML file, not in directive. And if i click on it, then nothing happens

Answer (score 2):

The result of `{{ }}` interpolation is a string. An object can't be passed like that.

Bindings are idiomatic here and thus preferable. The whole thing becomes messy when the directive is forced to use parent scope. However, it can be done by parsing scope properties manually with `$parse`:

```
  $scope.$watch(function () {
    var myDirectiveGetter = $parse($attrs.myDirective);
    return myDirectiveGetter($scope);
  }, ...);
```

This is a job for binding (`<` or `=`, depending on the case). If isolated scope isn't desirable, this can be done with inherited scope and `bindToController`:

```
scope: true,
bindToController: {
  myDirective: '<'
},
controllerAs: `vm`,
controller: function ($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('vm.myDirective', ...);
}
```

Notice that directive attribute is `my-directive`, not `myDirective`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. myDirective in the `tr` should be `my-directive`, as per Angular's
   conventions.
2. `{{row.data}}` prints the variable, you need to pass it without the
   `{{}}` for it to go through as an object.